# Visualising diagonal in asymmetric matrix plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, matrix, data-visualization

I have a number of symmetric matrices of the same dimensionality, and I wish to visualise the mean and variance of the values in each cell across these matrices in an elegant way (which I will make more precise below) that makes use of the symmetric character.

Let me start by making some data to illustrate. The following creates 10 9x9 matrices, aggregates the mean and variance, and transforms to long format in preparation for plotting:

```r
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(tidyr)

make_matrix <- function(n) {
  m <- matrix(NA, nrow = n, ncol = n)
  m[lower.tri(m)] <- runif((n^2 - n) / 2)
  m <- pmax(m, t(m), na.rm = TRUE)
  diag(m) <- runif(n)
  rownames(m) <- colnames(m) <- letters[1:n]
  m
}

matrices <- replicate(10, make_matrix(9))
means <- apply(matrices, 1:2, mean) %>% 
  as_tibble(rownames = "row") %>%
  pivot_longer(-1, names_to = "col", values_to = "mean")
vars <- apply(matrices, 1:2, var) %>%
  as_tibble(rownames = "row") %>%
  pivot_longer(-1, names_to = "col", values_to = "var")
df <- full_join(means, vars, by = c("row", "col"))

head(df)
#> # A tibble: 6 x 4
#>   row   col    mean    var
#>   <chr> <chr> <dbl>  <dbl>
#> 1 a     a     0.548 0.111 
#> 2 a     b     0.507 0.0914
#> 3 a     c     0.374 0.105 
#> 4 a     d     0.350 0.0976
#> 5 a     e     0.525 0.0752
#> 6 a     f     0.452 0.0887
```

Now, I could simply use `geom_tile` to make one plot of the means, and one plot of the variances. However, considering that both of these are symmetric, this wastes quite a lot of space, and also  fails to communicate the symmetric character to the audience.

To address this problem, I have been playing around with the `ggasym` package to create an asymmetric matrix plot. The following is a slight modification from the `ggasym` [vignette](https://jhrcook.github.io/ggasym/):

```r
library(ggasym)
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(x = col, y = row)) +
  geom_asymmat(aes(fill_diag = mean, fill_tl = mean, fill_br = var)) +
  scale_fill_diag_gradient(limits = c(0, 1), low = "lightpink", high = "tomato") +
  scale_fill_tl_gradient(limits = c(0, 1), low = "lightpink", high = "tomato") +
  scale_fill_br_gradient(low = "lightblue1", high = "dodgerblue") +
  geom_text(data = filter(df, row == col), aes(label = signif(var, 2)))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-06-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

What bothers me about this is the diagonal. In the above, I have mapped the fill of the diagonal to the means, and overlaid the variance by text, which works, but doesn't seem great. Specifically, **I would like to map all the information here to fill**, so as to get rid of the text. I see a couple of options for how to do this, but I am not sure how to implement any of them:

- Split the fill of the diagonal cells, so that (in the example above) the lower right of each cell on the diagonal is an appropriate shade of blue, while the upper left is some shade of red.
- Plot the upper and lower matrices separately (each with the diagonal), and then somehow "overlay" these plots so that they end up next to each other in an appropriate way. In other words, this would plot the diagonal twice.

I am open to other suggestions for how to accomplish this in a clean way. Let me emphasise that I do not require a solution building on `ggasym`, this was simply the closest I have been able to get so far. However, I would like some kind of `ggplot`-based solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here is my take on the 'split-the-fill' strategy. You can plot most of the things you would want in ggplot if you don't mind parameterising your stuff as polygons. We let the ggnewscale package handle the double fill mapping for us.

First off, we no longer autoname the matrices, as we will not use the dimnames.

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages({
  library(ggplot2)
  library(tidyr)
  library(dplyr)
  library(ggnewscale)
})

make_matrix <- function(n) {
  m <- matrix(NA, nrow = n, ncol = n)
  m[lower.tri(m)] <- runif((n^2 - n) / 2)
  m <- pmax(m, t(m), na.rm = TRUE)
  diag(m) <- runif(n)
  # rownames(m) <- colnames(m) <- letters[1:n]
  m
}
```

Below is a function that takes a matrix, parameterises it as a polygon and cuts off one half.

```
halfmat <- function(mat, side) {
  side <- match.arg(side, c("upper", "lower", "both"))
  # Convert to long format
  dat <- data.frame(
    x = as.vector(row(mat)),
    y = as.vector(col(mat)),
    id = seq_along(mat),
    value = as.vector(mat)
  )
  # Parameterise as polygon
  poly <- with(dat, data.frame(
    x = c(x - 0.5, x + 0.5, x + 0.5, x - 0.5),
    y = c(y - 0.5, y - 0.5, y + 0.5, y + 0.5),
    id = rep(id, 4),
    value = rep(value, 4)
  ))
  # Slice off one of the triangles
  if (side == "upper") {
    poly <- filter(poly, y >= x)
  } else if (side == "lower") {
    poly <- filter(poly, x >= y)
  }
  poly
}
```

Then we generate the data, compute the means and variances and reparameterise them.

```
matrices <- replicate(10, make_matrix(9))
means <- apply(matrices, 1:2, mean) %>% halfmat("upper")
vars <- apply(matrices, 1:2, var) %>% halfmat("lower")
```

Then we put in the means and variances as two seperate polygon layers, since we need to seperate the fill mappings with `new_scale_fill()`. There is a bit of extra fiddling with the scales, as these are now continuous instead of discrete, but it is not that bad.

```
ggplot(means, aes(x, y, fill = value, group = id)) +
  geom_polygon() +
  scale_fill_distiller(palette = "Reds", name = "Mean") +
  # Be sure to call new_scale_fill() only after you've set up a fill scale 
  # for the upper part
  new_scale_fill() +
  geom_polygon(data = vars, aes(fill = value)) +
  scale_fill_distiller(palette = "Blues", name = "Variance") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = function(x){seq(x[1] + 0.5, x[2] - 0.5, by = 1)},
                     labels = function(x){letters[x]},
                     expand = c(0,0), name = "col") +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = function(x){seq(x[1] + 0.5, x[2] - 0.5, by = 1)},
                     labels = function(x){letters[x]},
                     expand = c(0,0), name = "row")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-06-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>